# Why use second times loop function has error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let testOne = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}];
let testTwo = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}, {
  D: 4
}, {
  E: 5
}, {
  F: 6
}];


let questionNumber = function(testItem) {
  questionNumber = [];
  console.log(questionNumber);
  for (let i = 0; i < testItem.length; i++) {
    questionNumber.push(i);
  }
}

questionNumber(testOne);
console.log(questionNumber)

questionNumber(testTwo);
console.log(questionNumber)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

why console show questionNumber is not a function when calling function second times?
only call one function is work but two have a problem.

not make sense to me. because function first is a clean array.

should be not this error.

Comment: The first thing your `questionNumber` function does is re-define `questionNumber = []` so... yeah, it's not a function the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see the logs below,

- `questionNumber` is defined as the function for the first time.
- When first `questionNumber(testOne)` is called, `questionNumber` value will be reset as `testOne` values inside the function.
- Therefore, on the second call, `questionNumber` will be array so it is not able to call `questionNumber(testTwo)`.

```js
let testOne = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}];
let testTwo = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}, {
  D: 4
}, {
  E: 5
}, {
  F: 6
}];


let questionNumber = function(testItem) {
  questionNumber = [];
  console.log(questionNumber);
  for (let i = 0; i < testItem.length; i++) {
    questionNumber.push(i);
  }
}

questionNumber(testOne);
console.log(questionNumber)

console.log('Question Number', questionNumber);
questionNumber(testTwo);
console.log(questionNumber)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: How let loop function can by use several times on diftterent parameter ?

Comment: Simply, you can define another variable named like `questionNumberArr` above `questionNumber` definition with initial value `[]` and use that variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

`questionNumber` is defined duplicated as a function and variable.
You should set the different name.

```js
let testOne = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}];
let testTwo = [{
  A: 1
}, {
  B: 2
}, {
  C: 3
}, {
  D: 4
}, {
  E: 5
}, {
  F: 6
}];


let questionNumberFunc = function(testItem) {
  questionNumber = [];
  console.log(questionNumber);
  for (let i = 0; i < testItem.length; i++) {
    questionNumber.push(i);
  }
}

questionNumberFunc(testOne);
console.log(questionNumber)

questionNumberFunc(testTwo);
console.log(questionNumber)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```